# Am I using strcpy_s incorrectly?

Tags: c++, constructor, strcpy

I have a constructor for a Person class called "Person"  it looks like this:

```
    Person(const char * their_name, const char * email, int day, int month, int year)
        : name(0), email_address(0), birthday(day, month, year) {

        name = new char [strlen(their_name)+1];
        strcpy_s(name, strlen(their_name) +1, their_name);

        email_address = new char[strlen(email) + 1]; 
        strcpy_s(email_address, strlen(email) + 1, email); 

        cout << "\nPerson(...) FIRST CONSTRUCTOR CREATING: "<<name<<"\n";
        printOn(cout);
    }
```

I have private variables in this class:

```
private: 
    char * name; 
    char * email_address; 
    Date birthday;
```

I think there is an off by 1 error or something in here, because when I test my constructor like this in main:

```
Person *p1 = new Person("Sarah", "iam@awesome.com", 2,2,1000);
```

this prints to my console:

```
Person(...) FIRST CONSTRUCTOR CREATING: Sarah
ààà
```

I don't understand why it is printing the a's after the constructor runs... Can anyone see the issue?

EDIT:  My printOn method

```
/*print person on output stream o*/
    virtual void printOn(ostream & o) const { 
        //print person
         o << "………";
    }
```

and overriden << operator

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & ostr, const Person & p) { 
    p.printOn(ostr); 
    return ostr; 
}
```

Comment: Use `std::string`. All problems with `char*` solved.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: I have, it is only copying the first letter of the name and email, so it's only coping S and i

Comment: What does function  printOn(cout);
 do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what function  printOn(cout); does in your constructor. Can it be that it is its output?

As for function strcpy_s then there is no any need to use it. It would be much better to use old function strcpy. In your code you call strlen twice: one time when you allocate memory and the second time when you use strcpy_s.

Comment: Good call, I commented out the printOn(cout) line and it went away.

Comment: "No need to use `strcpy_s`"? The only way I agree with that is if the suggestion was to use `std::string` instead of using `strcpy`.

Comment: @crashmstr - it's pointless to use `strcpy_s` when the code has just allocated a buffer that is the right size. Writing correct code is not a matter of applying simplistic formulae, but of thinking about what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is using a different text encoding than your editor is. The character that shows as `…` in your code editor becomes `à` when you print it out.

In general, don't use high-ASCII characters unless you know how to choose the proper encoding, otherwise things won't work the way you think.